# Paypal API USER, PWD, SIGNATURE field lengths

Tags: optimization, paypal, datafield

I've gone through a number of pages and PDFs within the Paypal guides and x.com, but I can't find any reference to the maximum field lengths for the API login/connection. I see the Transaction ID maxes out at 19 characters, but they seem to avoid saying the maximums for the access fields.

I'm setting up a database table to hold multiple Paypal API logins as well as a section to edit it with I'll have validate by length. I want to use some real values instead of guessing 255 characters.

Surely someone must have been as specific as me in this regard, I'm hoping someone has found this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've always gone with 75 and that seems to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

On the NVP API Method and Field Reference page at http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/Appx_fieldreference.html they indicate EMAIL as "127 single byte characters".

As for the other items, I did not see any documented lengths, but checking 5 client accounts, it appears that

API PWD is 16 characters
API signature is 56 characters - in each account (these must be fixed length).